# Bell character(\a) to remove white space

Tags: c

How this program works to remove the white-space?:

```
int main()
{
    char s[]="remove   white     space";
    int i;
    for(i=0;s[i];++i)
            if(s[i]==' ')
                    s[i]='\a';
    printf("%s",s);
    return 0;
}
```

See output [here](http://ideone.com/GfSXz)

Output:

```
removewhitespace
```

Comment: The bell character is normally an invisible control character, along with quite a few others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not removing the whitespace, it's just replacing it with the bell character, which isn't printed by most terminals (instead, they usually produce a fastidious beep).

Although invisible on a terminal, those characters are obviously written on the standard output, so if you redirect to file the output of your program they will be written to disk, and can be displayed with most editors.

[image: The bell characters displayed in VIM]

Answer (score 1):

The `\a` is a nongraphic character and your program replaces all the whitespaces in the string with the `\a` nongraphic character.

See here from the standard (emphasis mine):

> (C99, 5.2.2p2) **Alphabetic escape sequences representing nongraphic characters** in the execution character set are intended to produce actions on display devices as follows:
>
> **\a** (alert) Produces an audible or visible alert **without changing the active position**.

Answer (score 0):

`\a` is a non-printable character - it makes a beep.
Thus, when the space character is replaced (in-place) with `\a`, and the string is sent to `printf()` the console beeps for each such bell-char instead of moving a single space.

Comment: I have always used sed to get rid of white space. For example, 'sed -e -i 's/[:space:]//g' $file', so maybe that is an alternative if you are printing ^G using 'printf()'

Answer (score 0):

1. In condition of stop (`s[i]`): it stops when special symbol `\0` comes.
2. It replace all spaces by not displayed symbol.